# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x

data types of the columns are:

```
Unnamed: 0                   object
Shear stress (τ) in N/m2     object
Unnamed: 2                   object
Unnamed: 3                  float64
Kte                          object
Unnamed: 5                   object
Kre                          object
Unnamed: 7                   object
Kae                          object
Unnamed: 9                   object
Unnamed: 10                 float64
Ktc                          object
Unnamed: 12                  object
Krc                          object
Unnamed: 14                  object
Kac                          object
Unnamed: 16                  object
Unnamed: 17                 float64
wdz                         float64
Unnamed: 19                 float64
Unnamed: 20                 float64
Unnamed: 21                 float64
Unnamed: 22                 float64
Unnamed: 23                 float64
Unnamed: 24                 float64
Unnamed: 25                 float64
Unnamed: 26                 float64
dFx                         float64
Unnamed: 28                 float64
dFy                         float64
Unnamed: 30                 float64
dFz                         float64
Unnamed: 32                 float64
Fx_1                          int64
Fy_1                          int64
Fz_1                          int64
Fx_2                          int64
Fy_2                          int64
Fz_2                          int64
dtype: object
```

Below is my code:

```
def integrand_x1(x, Kte_1, Ktc_1, Kae_1, Kac_1, Kre_1, Krc_1, Wdz):
    r = 0.0002
    f = 2/360*10**(-5)
    S = r + f*sin(x) - sqrt(r**2 - (f**2)*(cos(x))**2)
    
    dFa_1 = (Kac_1*S + Kae_1)*Wdz
    dFr_1 = (Krc_1*S + Kre_1)*Wdz
    dFt_1 = (Ktc_1*S + Kte_1)*Wdz
    
    return (cos(30*pi/180)*dFa_1 + sin(30*pi/180)*cos(5.4*pi/180)*dFr_1 - sin(30*pi/180)*sin(5.4*pi/180)*dFt_1)/((cos(30*pi/180))**2 + (sin(30*pi/180))**2*cos(2*5.4*pi/180))
def integrand_x2(x, Kte_2, Ktc_2, Kae_2, Kac_2, Kre_2, Krc_2, Wdz):
    r = 0.0002
    f = 2/360*10**(-5)
    S = r + f*sin(x) - sqrt(r**2 - (f**2)*(cos(x))**2)    

    dFa_2 = (Kac_2*S + Kae_2)*Wdz
    dFr_2 = (Krc_2*S + Kre_2)*Wdz
    dFt_2 = (Ktc_2*S + Kte_2)*Wdz
    
    return (cos(30*pi/180)*dFa_2 + sin(30*pi/180)*cos(5.4*pi/180)*dFr_2 - sin(30*pi/180)*sin(5.4*pi/180)*dFt_2)/((cos(30*pi/180))**2 + (sin(30*pi/180))**2*cos(2*5.4*pi/180))
Kte_1 = df.iloc[i,4]
Kte_2 = df.iloc[i,5]
Kre_1 = df.iloc[i,6]
Kre_2 = df.iloc[i,7]
Kae_1 = df.iloc[i,8]
Kae_2 = df.iloc[i,9]

Ktc_1 = df.iloc[i,11]
Ktc_2 = df.iloc[i,12]
Krc_1 = df.iloc[i,13]
Krc_2 = df.iloc[i,14]
Kac_1 = df.iloc[i,15]
Kac_2 = df.iloc[i,16]

t = (df.iloc[i,0])
Wdz = t/sin(31.19*pi/180)

df['Fx_1'] = 0
df['Fy_1'] = 0
df['Fz_1'] = 0
df['Fx_2'] = 0
df['Fy_2'] = 0
df['Fz_2'] = 0
for i in range(0,1999,1):
    df.Fx_1.iloc[i] = quad(integrand_x1, 95*pi/180, 0, args=(Kte_1, Ktc_1, Kae_1, Kac_1, Kre_1, Krc_1, Wdz)) + quad(integrand_x1, 0, 15*pi/180, args=(Kte_1, Ktc_1, Kae_1, Kac_1, Kre_1, Krc_1, Wdz))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quad return a tuple and you try to add two tuple in last line.

Comment: I removed the second quad term and it still gave the same error

Comment: Could you try `df.Fx_1.iloc[i], err = quad(....`  ?

Comment: Hey but the whole column Fx_1 is having the same value. That shouldn't be happening because Ktc_1, Kac_1 etc are all changing with "i". Please help

Comment: You have to review your implementation. I dont know  what you compute precisely. Quad returns two numbers. The first is the value of the integral, and the second is an estimate of the absolute error in the value of the integral. Inception you have quad(..) + quad(...). If quad(...) return (1,2), quad(..) + quad(...) merge two tuple (1,2,1,2).  You want provably do 1+1 = 2

Comment: No its not about that addition. I took out the second term. The problem is "i". In the dataframe for different values of "i" all columns have different values. Yet, the whole column after the integration has the same value.